# How can send mail as a text file from localhost to a folder mail to disk in xampp version 7.1.6 / PHP 7.1.6

Tags: xampp

How can send mail as a text file from localhost to a folder mail to disk in
xampp version 7.1.6 / PHP 7.1.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How can send mail as a text file from localhost to a folder mail to disk in
xampp version 7.1.6 / PHP 7.1.6

There is a file with extension mailtodisc

you can configure C:\xampp\php\php.ini

in C:\xampp\php\php.ini 
find extension=php_openssl.dll and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

in php.ini file find [mail function]

un comment following line if there is another 
sendmail_path : sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe" in the php.ini file

Also remember to restart the server using the XAMMP control panel so the changes take effect.

Comment: The output file has multipart data with Base64 encoding!
How do I pretty print the file in an HTML document?